# ¿Cómo transponer columnas en filas leyendo desde un archo de texto?

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable, text

Por favor su ayuda. Estoy leyendo desde un archivo de texto, donde los datos se organizan en una sola columna, aunque están estructurados. Necesito colocar los datos leidos en ocho columnas.
Datos en archivo:
05
02
01
02
00
000
00
Barro Arriba (DM)

Datos daspués de ser leídos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto es lo que he estado haciendo:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);             

            if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                FileInputStream input;
                InputStreamReader isr;

                try {

                    input = new FileInputStream(file);
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    int read = 0;
                    String linea = "";
                    String header[] = {"Región", "Provincia", "Municipio", "Distrito_municipal", "Sección", "Barrio_paraje", "Sub_barrio", "Toponimia_o_Nombre"};
                    Object dataRow [][] = {};
                    JTable table = new JTable(null, header);
                    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(header, 0);

                    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                    panelTable.add(scrollPane);


                    while((linea = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null) {

                        String newLine[] = linea.split("\r");
                        dtm.addRow(newLine);


                    }

                    table.setModel(dtm);
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    guardado = false;

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    //e1.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error leyendo archivo", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

                mainForm.setTitle("Archivo: " + file.toString());
                mainForm.revalidate();
                mainForm.repaint();



            }
```

Actualmente, todos los datos se cargan en la primera columna.
Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Cambiar el caracter del split por `String newLine[] = linea.split(" ");` sin embargo ocasionaria problema con el último campo cuando hay más de una palabra por lo que deberia controlar el número de columnas iniciales (7 para el ejemplo) y la octava columna un concatenado de los datos restantes.

Comment: @isaac, gracias por tu comentario.
Encontré porque no funcionaba; debido a que los datos están en una única columna, utilizar `split()` es innecesario y siempre pasará a `newLine[]` un único elemento e insertará el próximo elemento leido en la siguiente línea. Para resolverlo, paso a `newLine[]` un array de 8 elementos. Así se crea un registro completo.

De todos modos, lo que sugires no funcionaría ya que cada vez que lea una línea, la colocará en una única columna y cuando encuentre un string de varias palabras la va a dividir en varias columnas, según vaya encontrando espacios en blanco.